# Running SSLSocket asynchronously

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I am trying to encrypt the data flowing through a socket using OpenSSL. My operating system is Linux. The problem is with the client side.

---

This code is successfully sending SSL using BIO:

```cpp
    m_pSSL = SSL_new(m_pCTX);

    m_rBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    m_wBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    SSL_set_fd(m_pSSL, m_nSocketId);   /* attach the socket descriptor */

    if ( SSL_connect(m_pSSL) == -1 )   /* perform the connection */
    {

        close(nSock);
        return false;
    }

    SSL_set_bio(m_pSSL, m_rBIO, m_wBIO);
```

---

Send code

```cpp
    char buf[MEM_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0, };

    int writtenLength = SSL_write(m_pSSL, pbuf, size);

    int bioWrittenLength = BIO_number_written(m_wBIO);

    int len = BIO_read(m_wBIO, buf, bioWrittenLength);

    ssize_t s = send(m_nSocketId, buf, bioWrittenLength, MSG_EOR | MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

However, receiving using SSL failed:

```
char buf[MEM_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0, };

ssize_t s = recv(m_nSocketId, buf, size, MSG_DONTWAIT);

if(s < 0)
{
    if(errno != EAGAIN) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


int writtenLength = BIO_write(m_rBIO, buf, s);

if(writtenLength <= 0) {
    return -1;
}

int bioWrittenLength = BIO_number_written(m_rBIO); // 복호화된 내용의 길이를 가져온다.


s = SSL_read(m_pSSL, pbuf,size);

if(s <= 0)
{
    int error = SSL_get_error(m_pSSL, bioWrittenLength);

}
```

The return value of SSL_read is always -1 and the return value of SSL_get_error is always 0.

Comment: Why do you call `SSL_get_error` with `bioWrittenLength` as argument? It is documented to be called with the return value from `SSL_read`, i.e. `s`.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich Thank you. As you said, I made a mistake.
But this code doesn't work.

Comment: *"But this code doesn't work"* - if you call `SSL_get_error` the way it was intended you likely get more information about your error and can update your question with the details. Then one could maybe give you more help or maybe you can already fix the problem yourself once you have the proper error information.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich Thank you. I'll revise the article as you say.